# golang -- Cannot create user when using user & password to connect to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying out the Chitchat go app from the book Go Web Programming. The original version works. When I use a user & password to access postgresql, it can connect to db but fails to create a new User, as shown below:

```
func db() (database *sql.DB) {
    database, err := sql.Open("postgres", "dbname=chitchat user=tom password=tomahawk sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        fmt.Println("Db connection failed")
    }
    return
}
```

Here's the full code on [Github](https://github.com/mjwong/chitchat).

However, I've found a temporary solution but it requires granting access to all the sequences in the chitchat database. Even after I've applied a

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE chitchat to tom;
```

it still requires manual grants to each of the table sequences. Here're the steps taken:

1) Grant access to database

```
GRANT all privileges on database chitchat to tom;
```

2) List all sequences in chitchat database

```
SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
```

3) Grant access to each of them

```
GRANT all privileges on sequence users_id_seq to tom;
GRANT all privileges on sequence threads_id_seq to tom;
GRANT all privileges on sequence posts_id_seq to tom;
GRANT all privileges on sequence sessions_id_seq to tom;
```

Is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only superuser can crete users in your postgress database. so make it so ..

`ALTER USER tom WITH SUPERUSER;`

Comment: The question is poorly worded in this respect, but I'm pretty sure they're talking about creating an application user (e.g. [a plain insert into a `users` table](https://github.com/mjwong/chitchat/blob/95c4b27328afdceaf0d0b40af8a02b4fa8cc163f/data/user.go#L115)) and they are not trying to create a new PostgreSQL user/role. Just as with uid 0/`root` in Unix, having an application connect using a user/role with completely and total access to the database is a bad idea.